# How to discover Internal-only ASP.NET Core stateless service inside of Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi

I have ASP.NET Core API which should be visible only inside of Azure Service Fabric. When I follow the [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore) I would use Kestrel to host the application and let the Azure Service Fabric to dynamically assign the port.

How to discover the service inside of ASP.NET Core Web application and what is the preferred way? [DNS service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice), Naming service or [Reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided example, running aspnet core api inside Service Fabric means having a Reliable Service, and exposing a `KestrelCommunicationListener` from it.
So you're simply hosting aspnetcore inside a service. (other example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-core-getting-started))
Usually you don't access the hosting service from inside the controller.

You may want to access a different stateless service from a controller, in that case you can use SF [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) for minimal overhead.

Or if you must access a different aspnet core api running inside the cluster, a simple way to locate that api is by using the [DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice) based approach.

Note: Don't use the reverse proxy for this case, as it exposes all http based endpoints to the outside world.